# JAVA: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Set<IConnection>> to Iterator<IConnection>

Tags: apache-flex, red5

I have a Problem here using Java in Red5 0.9 Server here's the code

```
package com.hwakin.i5lc.manager;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IClient;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.Red5;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IServiceCapableConnection;

import com.hwakin.i5l.vo.ExternalPoint;
import com.hwakin.i5l.vo.UserInfo;
import com.hwakin.i5lc.vo.ExternalDrawInfo;

public class I5lcDrawManager extends ApplicationAdapter {
    protected static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(I5lcDrawManager.class.getName());

public void startDrawingHandler(String type,ExternalPoint point, ExternalDrawInfo data){

         try{
            IConnection Lconn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();

            IScope scope = Lconn.getScope();

            Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                IConnection conn = it.next();

                if (Lconn.equals(conn)) {
                    continue;
                }

                log.info("i5lvDrawManagerReceiver.startDrawingHandler invoked.");

                IClient client = conn.getClient();

                UserInfo userInfo =(UserInfo) client.getAttribute("userInfo");


                if (conn instanceof IServiceCapableConnection) {
                    if(userInfo.lectureInfo.sync.equals("true")){

                        ((IServiceCapableConnection) conn).invoke("invoke",new Object[]{"i5lvDrawManagerReceiver.startDrawingHandler",type,point,data});
                    }       
                }   
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
                log.debug("Exception in noticeChattingTo Method:"+e);
        }
    }
    public void drawingHandler(String type,ExternalPoint point){

         try{
            IConnection Lconn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
            IScope scope = Lconn.getScope();

            Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                IConnection conn = it.next();

                if (Lconn.equals(conn)) {
                    continue;
                }

                log.info("i5lvDrawManagerReceiver.drawingHandler invoked.");

                IClient client = conn.getClient();

                UserInfo userInfo =(UserInfo) client.getAttribute("userInfo");


                if (conn instanceof IServiceCapableConnection) {
                    if(userInfo.lectureInfo.sync.equals("true")){

                        ((IServiceCapableConnection) conn).invoke("invoke",new Object[]{"i5lvDrawManagerReceiver.drawingHandler",type,point});

                    }

                }   
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
                log.debug("Exception in noticeChattingTo Method:"+e);
        }
    }

    public void endDrawingHandler(String type,ExternalPoint point, ExternalDrawInfo data){

         try{
            IConnection Lconn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
            IScope scope = Lconn.getScope();

            Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                IConnection conn = it.next();

                if (Lconn.equals(conn)) {
                    continue;
                }

                log.info("i5lvDrawManagerReceiver.endDrawingHandler invoked.");

                IClient client = conn.getClient();

                UserInfo userInfo =(UserInfo) client.getAttribute("userInfo");


                if (conn instanceof IServiceCapableConnection) {
                    if(userInfo.lectureInfo.sync.equals("true")){

                        ((IServiceCapableConnection) conn).invoke("invoke",new Object[]{"i5lvDrawManagerReceiver.endDrawingHandler",type,point,data});
                    }       
                }   
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
                log.debug("Exception in noticeChattingTo Method:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

The Errors are:

1. ERROR in /opt/red5/dist/webapps/i5lecture/WEB-INF/src/com/hwakin/i5lc/manager/I5lcDrawManager.java (at line 29)

   ```
   Iterator <IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();
   ```

### Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Set<IConnection>> to Iterator

2. ERROR in /opt/red5/dist/webapps/i5lecture/WEB-INF/src/com/hwakin/i5lc/manager/I5lcDrawManager.java (at line 63)

   ```
   Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();
   ```

### Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Set<IConnection>>  to Iterator<IConnection>

3. ERROR in /opt/red5/dist/webapps/i5lecture/WEB-INF/src/com/hwakin/i5lc/manager/I5lcDrawManager.java (at line 100)

   ```
   Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();
   ```

### Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Set<IConnection>>  to Iterator<IConnection>

3 problems (3 errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Added (Iterator) to parse scope.getConnection();

```
Iterator<IConnection> it = (Iterator) scope.getConnections();
```

Then I added @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in the beginning of the function

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void startDrawingHandler(String type,ExternalPoint point, ExternalDrawInfo data){

   // Rest of the code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `getConnections()` method returns `Collection<Set<IConnection>>` while you seem to think that it should return `Iterator<IConnection>`.

Are you forgetting the call to `.iterator()`? Such as

```
Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections.iterator();
```

although from the compiler error it sounds as if you'll need

```
Iterator<Set<IConnection>> it = scope.getConnections.iterator();
```

Comment: there is no iterator() property for scope.getConnections
getConnections returns Iterator<IConnection> as shown here

http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/api/class-use/IConnection.html

Comment: The error message is clearly telling you that scope.getConnections() is returning a Collection<Set<IConnection>>.

Answer (score 2):

A `Collection` is an `Iterable`, not an `Iterator`. You don't need an `Iterator` for looping; the enhanced for loop works with any `Iterable` implementation.

Try this instead:

```
for (Set<IConnection>> connections : scope.getConnections()) {
  for (IConnection con : connections) {
    /* Use each 'conn' instance... */
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your code. can you please state the whole code for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to have here is an unstable API.

Is it [`Iterator<IConnection> getConnections()`](http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/api/IScope.html#getConnections()) or [`Collection<Set<IConnection>> getConnections()`](http://api.red5.nl/org/red5/server/api/IScope.html#getConnections()) (nicely documents as "Get a connection iterator." - comments lie)? Google is your friend.

Comment: Iterator<IConnection> getConnections()

as the code states:

Iterator<IConnection> it = scope.getConnections();

Comment: As your code states? But what about the code you are using? There are clearly at least two versions floating about. You can use `javap` to find out what really is in the class files/jars that you are using.